# Numbers of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{N} 2^{a_n} 3^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Just out of curiosity.
Does the numbers of the form
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=0}^{N} 2^{a_n} 3^n \text{,}
\end{align}
with $a_n \ge 0$ and $N \ge 0$, cover all integers not divisible by 3?

These numbers can never be divisible by three.
It is also easy to discover integers with multiple representations (e.g., $4 = 2^2 3^0 = 2^0 3^0 + 2^0 3^1$).
I am however stuck to prove that they cover all integers not divisible by 3.

Second question: The numbers of the form
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=0}^{N} 5^{a_n} 3^n \text{,}
\end{align}
with $a_n \ge 0$ and $N \ge 0$, are numbers congruent to $\{1, 4, 5, 8\} \pmod{12}$.
These are the numbers not divisible by 3 and not $\{ 2, 3 \} \pmod{4}$.
Many other such forms may be considered.
What is the name of such numbers (numbers of such a form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \le 8$, then all numbers not divisible by $3$ have the desired form as one can check by hand (e.g. $1=1$, $2=2$, $4=4$, $5=2+3$, $7=1+2 \cdot 3$, $8 = 8$).

If $x > 8$, and $x \equiv 1,2,4,5,7,8 \bmod 9$, then let $m = 4,8,1,2,4,2$ respectively, so $m$ is a power of $2$ and $x \equiv m \bmod 3$ but $x \not\equiv m \bmod 9$. Now write

$$x = m + 3y$$

Now, by construction, $y<x$ is not divisible by $3$. By induction, it has the required form, which implies that $x$ also has the required form. Indeed from this proof you see that one can take the power of $2$ to be in the set $\{1,2,4,8\}$.

Comment: Does this also prove that $x$ covers **all** integers $\{ 1, 2 \} \pmod{3}$?

Comment: @DaBler Of course --- do you know about proof by induction? Can you see that any integer which is $1,2 \bmod 3$ is $1,2,4,5,7,8 \bmod 9$?

Comment: No sure. So you start with $y \equiv \{ 1, 2 \} \pmod{3}$. Then you consider $x = 3y + \{ 1, 2, 4, 8 \}$, which implies that $x \equiv \{ 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 \} \pmod{9}$. And then repeat this step so that you cover all necessary residues modulo 27, 81, etc. Do I get it right?

Comment: @DaBler You don't have to consider anything modulo $27$. The proof (that all $x \equiv 1,2 \bmod 3$) have such a representation is a proof by induction. You first check it is true for $x \le 8$. Now take $x \ge 8$, and assume the result is true for all $y < 8$ which are $1,2 \bmod 3$. The answer explains how to write $x = m + 3y$ for some $y < x$ which is $1,2 \bmod 3$, and now by induction one knows that  $y$ has the required form. But this implies that $x$ has the required form as well, so done.

Comment: Why doesn't this construction work only with $x<3$ as the base case, and then with the induction step $x = 3y + \{1, 2\}$, which covers $\{4, 5, 7, 8\} \pmod{9}$? (I know your answer is correct because I tried it computationally.)

Comment: @DaBler Because $x-1$ or $x-2$ might be divisible by $9$, and then $y$ is would be divisible by $3$. The point of working with $x \pmod 9$ is to choose a power of $2$ $m$ so that $x \equiv m \mod 3$ but $x \not\equiv m \mod 9$, this guarantees that when you write $x-m=3y$ that $y$ is *not* divisible by $3$. That's the key point.

Answer (score 5):

Well as far as the first question every integer$M$ can be written $\sum_{n=0} a_i3^n$ where $a_i =0,1=2^0$, or $2^1=2$ i.e., $M$'s tertiary expansion. So yes to the first question.

Comment: However, this is a different definition than the one in the question. In the question, $2^{a_n}$ cannot be zero. So, the definition does not cover all integers. In other words, the digit "0" is excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Erdos asked a similar question some time ago (about “3-smooth representations” of the natural numbers). See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589404?seq=1%20%22here%22.) for a discussion on both of your questions.