To prove that every natural number other than multiples of 3 can be written in the form of a linear combination of powers of 3's and 2's.
My Question is to prove as follows:

Every natural number other than multiples of 3 can be written in the form of a linear combination of increasing powers of 3 and decreasing powers of 2.


NOTE: I used the word linear combination to say that each increasing term of $3^r$ is multiplied with the term $2^{a_{r+1}}$, where all $a_{r+1}$ are unique, and $a_r > a_{r+1}$.

ALSO NOTE: I have independently come up with this equation. If this can be disproven, please give an explanation for the same as both proving/disproving will help me.

In other words,
$k = 3^02^{a_1} + 3^12^{a_2} + 3^22^{a_3} +...+3^n2^{a_{n+1}}$
Where,

$k$ is a Natural number
$a_1$, $a_2$,...,$a_{n+1}$ are all Whole numbers, such that in the sequence, $a_1>a_2>a_3>...>a_{n+1}$
Also note that $a_1,a_2,...$ need NOT be in AP.
But, yes, the exponents of "3" are successive, pre-set numbers. The exponent of 3 in the first term is 0, next is 1, then 2, 3, 4,...,n.
Thus, you can see that there are $n+1$ terms,all unique.


Some examples for clarification.
The question is to prove that all Natural numbers other than multiples of 3 can be written in this form:-
$k = 3^02^{a_1} + 3^12^{a_2} + 3^22^{a_3} +...+3^n2^{a_{n+1}}$
For Example:

$1 = 2^0$
$2 = 2^1$
$4 = 2^2$
$5 = 2^1 + 3^12^0$
$7 = 2^2 + 3^12^0$
$8 = 2^3$
$10 = 2^2 + 3^12^1$


This seems intuitive that this is possible for all numbers. But the catch is that powers of 2 are decreasing and not in any random order.


Can this form of natural numbers be proven / disproven?
Both the proof or the counter-example will help me.

Source:
I have been trying to untangled the Collatz conjecture. Proving this statement would be a giant leap towards solving the 87 years old problem. I have come up with this on my own. So, if there are some edits or counter-examples, please elaborate them in the answers.

Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957376/numbers-of-the-form-sum-n-0n-2a-n-3n

$13$ is a counterexample. Since $13=1\mod3$, the first power of $2$ is either $1$ or $4$. In both cases, it is easy to check that there’s no decomposition of the desired type.

However, if you want a weaker decomposition of the type
$$
k = \sum_{i=1}^n 3^{b_i} 2^{a_i},
$$
where $0=b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_n$ and $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_n$, then the following greedy algorithm works.
If $k$ is a power of $2$, we are done. If not, let $2^{a_1}$ be the largest power of $2$ such that $2^{a_1} < k$ and $2^{a_1}=k \mod 3$. Let $k’ = \frac1{3^{\ell}}(k-2^{a_1})$, where $3^\ell$ is the largest power of $3$ that divides $k-2^{a_1}$ (note that $\ell\ge 1$). Repeat the above steps for $k’$. It is clear that $a_2 < a_1$ because $2^{a_2} < k’$ and $k-2^{a_1} < 3\cdot 2^{a_1} \le 3^{\ell} 2^{a_1}$.

Thanks a lot, Pranay.
